# Why did Nick Fury not hesitate in blowing up the plane he thought was carrying a nuke?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

In *The Avengers*, the Council contacted Nick Fury and supposedly, they want to nuke Manhattan. Nick didn't agree so they contacted a S.H.I.E.L.D. operative to nuke Manhattan.

When they found out that an unauthorized jet was trying to fly, Nick grabbed a rocket launcher and fired it at the jet, which was a decoy and the real jet was able to escape.

However, why would he do that? If that was the real plane carrying a nuke enough to level Manhattan, wouldn't the nuke explode and destroy the base along with them if he fired a rocket launcher at it?

Comment: Just to give you an idea how hard it is to detonate a nuclear bomb, you need an explosion of an atomic bomb to trigger explosion of a hydrogen bomb.

Comment: I don't believe the first plane was intended as a decoy. I think there were simply two pilots following the orders of the Council. Fury got the first one but didn't expect a second.

Comment: It was still a pretty stupid thing to do. The bomb will not likely detonate, but it can still make a pretty good “dirty bomb”, spreading radioactive material all over. Better to simply disable the plane? (I have not seen the movie.)

Comment: @Dúthomhas: If the nukes were uranium based, [it would make for a terrible dirty bomb](https://fas.org/programs/ssp/nukes/non-proliferation%20and%20arms%20control/uraniumdirtybombs.html). The half-life is so long that you'd need literally tons of it to produce an appreciable risk factor. Distributing the contents of a plutonium based nuke would be a lot dirtier, but if Nick knew it was uranium based, blowing it up is about as dirty as getting a couple unnecessary x-rays; a couple more people on the helicarrier might get cancer in old age, but that's a lot better than a few million blowing up.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: You should note that "a couple of unnecessary X-rays", which are in reality alpha radiation is **not** the concern with exploding an uranium device. In fact, not only can you carry uranium around in your pocket quite safely without protection, you can even use it as radiation shield (that's actually being done). Alpha radiators are perfectly harmless. Alpha radiators _inside your body_ (such as after inhaling uranium dust) are a _very_ different story. They're about as bad as it can get. That's notwithstanding the significant toxicity of uranium.

Comment: Are you really asking why Nick Fury did not hesitate facing the choice between a few hundred military personnel (in the *extremely* unlikely event the bomb would do damage to the carrier) and a few million civilians? Especially given that the heroes are perfectly willing to risk their lives with far greater risk and far lower stakes many, many times over?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> If that was the real plane carrying a nuke enough to level Manhattan, wouldn't the nuke explode and destroy the base along with them if he fired a rocket launcher at it?

## No.

Detonating a modern nuclear device is, in fact, **incredibly difficult** and merely shooting down the aircraft carrying it would not be sufficient.

In fact, several aircraft carrying older nuclear devices have either crashed or otherwise been lost without the device on board detonating.

It's likely that the crash might cause a release of nuclear material but detonation is practically impossible.

In 1966...

> ...another B-52 carrying four hydrogen bombs crashed near the Spanish town of Palomares on Spain’s southeast coast after colliding with a refueling tanker. One of the four bombs was recovered virtually intact, according to The Washington Post, but two others released plutonium when their explosive triggers detonated. A fourth bomb fell into the sea, prompting a search that involved thousands of uniformed personnel, millions of dollars and 20 ships that ranged from submarines to minesweepers.
>
> The fourth bomb was eventually recovered, but radiation released by the damaged weapons required a U.S.-led effort to decontaminate 640 acres of topsoil in the farmland around Palomares, Tad Sczulc reported in the Times. Military personnel initially wore face masks and gloves as they removed the soil, according to Sczulc’s account, and more than 1,600 tons of contaminated soil were sealed in steel drums and shipped to the U.S. for disposal.
>
> <sup>[*Washington Post*](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/retropolis/wp/2018/01/21/cataclysmic-cargo-the-hunt-for-four-missing-nuclear-bombs-after-a-b-52-crash/?utm_term=.55f162089d6d)</sup>

1964

> In 1964, a B-52 carrying two unarmed atomic bombs crashed in western Maryland. In 1961, two nuclear-laden B-52s went down — one near Yuba City, Calif., and another north of Goldsboro, N.C. The bombs survived both crashes without detonating

Comment: So even if, by the chance, the rocket hit the nuke directly or exploded so close to the nuke inside the jet, it wouldn't explode?

Comment: @I.Am only if the specific detonation criteria are met. This could happen but you must consider that these weapons are designed to be difficult to set off, to minimise the risk of them being set off accidentally. There is no "they would 100% not go off" but that isn't the point of the scene.

Comment: Nuclear devices require a "super critical mass" in order to detonate in a nuclear fission (fusion devices require a fission starter). This is done either by shooting a uranium slug into a uranium sphere (the slug is stored such that it must be armed and dropped before it was even aimed at the sphere) or by compressing a uranium sphere through the use of precisely timed explosive pressure waves (any deviation from the precise timing results in the sphere being obliterated instead of initiating fission). The latter is more common. In short, Nick's RPG blast would disarm the nuke if hit.

Comment: @I.Am The macguffin in the Harrison Ford thriller "Frantic" is a high-precision switch called a krytron, which nefarious agents are trying to steal because it's the sort of thing you need to set off the explosives surrounding a nuclear core simultaneously enough to make the material supercritical rather than splatter it off to one side or the other.

Comment: While I largely agree, it's important not to be complacent about crashes with A-bombs. In the Goldsboro crash at least two of the bombs nearly went off. (In one bomb, three of the four safety devices failed). But that was because the firing circuit was almost activated by relatively light damage to the bomb. Blowing one up at altitude is a good way to stop that happening, sure.

It also exposes the lie of various supercomputers used to "keep our bomb stockpile safe". An old, rotted bomb won't go off for your reasons. What these guys are doing is keeping their bomb-stockpile *dangerous*.

Comment: "*Detonating a nuclear device is, in fact, incredibly difficult*" - well, no, [that depends on which nuclear device](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/52520).

Comment: @jeffronicus I actually thought of Tom Clancy's *The Sum of All Fears*, where a plane carrying a nuclear bomb goes down, and the unexploded bomb falls into the hands of terrorists.

Comment: @MasonWheeler There have been several accidents that resulted in nuclear bombs being dropped because the aircraft carrying them was damaged or destroyed that likely served as inspiration for Clancey's story and which confirmed that a bomb could survive the fall intact.

Comment: @i.am virtually all nukes are implosion devices.  To achieve critical mass, the implosion has to be absolutely perfect. if it is imperfect, you don't get critical mass, the mass squishes out toward the slow side of the explosion.  Even what Nicole Kidman did in "The Peacemaker" is more than enough; she could have unplugged one wire but she didn't want to risk a partial criticality aka a fizzle.

Comment: @DanNeely more than that, some nukes are designed to detonate after they impact, and their casing is a ground penetrator.   So they definitely can survive a fall.

Comment: @Dannie, "three out of four safety devices failed" is one of those true but misleading facts that keeps getting thrown around.  Yes, three out of four arming mechanisms were activated, but the purpose of those mechanisms is to keep the bomb from detonating while still in the aircraft, or during ground handling.  When the bomb left the airplane, it's not surprising that those three activated.  The purpose of the fourth safety mechanism, the "safe/arm" switch, is to keep the bomb from going off when the crew doesn't want it to.  That one was still set to "safe" when the bomb left the aircraft.

Comment: It's important in this conversation to distinguish two major types of nukes: [gun-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun-type_fission_weapon) and implosion. Gun-type nukes, like Little Boy, operate by shooting a sub-critical mass into another sub-critical mass. They are simple, so simple the first wasn't even tested, but unsafe and inefficient. Nobody's made them in decades, they're irrelevant. Instead nearly every nuke today requires a very, very, very precise implosion to squeeze the material together; the hard part is getting that right. Damage an implosion bomb and it simply won't work.

Answer (score 10):

Just because the bomb has been dropped doesn't mean the mechanism to detonate/criteria required for detonation has been met. There are several real life incidents where a nuclear bomb has been dropped and didn't detonate - either because [it was dropped and the mechanism failed](https://www.businessinsider.com/nuclear-bomb-accident-goldsboro-nc-swamp-2017-5?r=US&IR=T) or because [the plane carrying the bomb crashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1961_Goldsboro_B-52_crash).

Now that we have that out of the way, the rest of the answer to your question is really simple: The World Security Council had just launched a nuclear weapon targeted at a civilian population. Nick Fury was doing what he thought needed to be done to get the situation back under control. It would have been a non-issue for him if the nuke had gone off in the skies above New York and destroyed the helicarrier - this is for the greater good in comparison to nuking Manhattan.

Comment: I see. So he's someone willing to sacrifice his life and all of SHIELD's operatives?

Comment: SHEILD operatives are not civilians - they signed up for the mission. Yes - Nick Fury is willing to sacrifice a helicarrier of SHIELD agents to save Manhattan from a nuke and he's willing to make that choice without a moments delay.

Comment: I like this answer, because while yes in reality a nuke wouldn't go off, but in film logic a nuke would go off when shot. (Though I am not sure of thats what was implied in the Avengers Movie, or the MCU in general)

Comment: Black Widow summarized this kind of decision quite well in Age of Ultron: "Everybody up here vs everyone down there? There's no math there".

Comment: One issue here: if a nuke goes off in the skies above New York, that's actually how you would go about nuking Manhattan if that were your actual goal. Nukes are typically detonated hundreds to thousands of feet in the air (called an 'air burst.') The Hiroshima bomb was detonated around 2,000 ft up, for example. You would have to be _many miles_ up for an air burst not to result in nuking the city below. Basically, if the air is dense enough to fly and you detonate a nuke, you have nuked everything beneath you. The effect wouldn't be as bad from 20,000-30,000 ft as 2,000, but still quite bad.

Comment: Sure thing @reirab but lets use some actual numbers. Some missiles travel up to mach 10 so in the 10 minutes since the missile has launched it has travelled up to 1250 miles. A 1megaton bomb (80x Hiroshima) has a blast radius of 10-15 miles plus an additional 5-10 miles of fallout. [This will help you visualise it](https://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/) - either way we know the helicarrier was well out to sea because of time it took the plane to get from the helicarrier to Manhatten, and the additional time from missile launch to Iron Man resolving the situation.

Comment: @user5603 Cruise missiles and air-ground missiles rarely fly anywhere near Mach 10. A Tomahawk flies around Mach 0.74, for example, similar to a short-haul airliner. Mach 10 is more like ICBMs (though Mach number isn't terribly meaningful there, since most of the flight is in space.) It's been a while since I've seen the movie, but, based on the times you say, though, yeah, you're right that it would have been well offshore (probably ~50-100 miles.) It was more the "if the nuke had gone off in the skies above New York" part that I was responding to.

Comment: @reirab the Trident nuclear system flies at upto ~mach 24 (approx 18,030 mph). ICBM is literally how most other countries deploy theirs... However, to avoid the extreme ends of the discussion - even using conservative numbers like saying everything is moving at maximum mach 2 still means the helicarrier is 400 miles away. If a nuke airbursts at cruising altitude 400 miles away you're really not going to notice much. It would certainly qualify as "saving the city".

Comment: @user5603 Trident is a ballistic missile. That's why it flies so fast in terminal phase. The missile in the movie wasn't ballistic, so its speed profile would be relatively flat. At any rate, I completely agree that a blast even just 50-100 mi away wouldn't be catastrophic like a direct hit, but I was responding to the part about if it had "gone off in the skies above New York," assuming that you meant the city of NY. Might be worth rewording that to something like "if it had gone off in the skies out to sea where the helicarrier was."

Comment: [If it had gone off above Avengers tower (ie: the Portal) as originally intended then it would have been devastating](https://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/?&kt=1000&lat=40.761821&lng=-73.9755821&airburst=0&hob_ft=0&casualties=1&fallout=1&psi=20,5,1&fatalities=1540782&injuries=1418656&psi_1=5165419&zm=7)

Answer (score 5):

### Hitting a nuke with another explosive would cause it to fizzle.

Nuclear bombs have different "levels" of detonation. It's not an all-or-nothing thing where the bomb either does not react at all, or explodes in an all-out violent nuclear explosion. If a bomb is subject to extreme external pressure, for example by falling into the ocean or getting hit with another bomb, it is likely to "fizzle". This is caused by the chemical explosives going off, but not with the precise timing required to initiate complete nuclear fission. It results in a very weak nuclear blast with a minuscule yield.

### A rocket launcher does not destroy a plane right away.

There's another important point to make. A rocket launcher does not obliterate an airplane when it detonates. It explodes and throws shrapnel everywhere, severing hydraulic lines and damaging the aircraft structurally. The plane would not be turned to smoke and instead would continue flying for a short time before crashing in a ball of fire. It's even possible for it to continue to fly for hours. Furthermore, guided missiles do not always hit their targets, and when they do, they do not always cause sufficient damage to bring them down. During that time when the plane is uncontrollable but before it hits the ground, someone could arm and detonate the nuclear device.

Comment: Did you take into account that movies operate with a different set of physical properties? Like how a few pistol shots cause a car to explode as if it'd been packed with dynamite? With that in mind, it seem *very* plausible that even a gracing hit would detonate the nuclear bomb. `Disclaimer: I'm joking`

Comment: @Gertsen Actually, even in movies, nukes are often shown to be handled rather haphazardly with little concern for an unplanned nuclear explosion. When people are scolded for that handling, it's about the conventional explosives going off, not the nuke - still quite enough to kill everyone in the room, mind.